# Weak convergence in a reﬂexive, separable and infinite Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

Let $Y$ be a infinite Banach space and $X$ be a reﬂexive, separable and infinite Banach space. Further let $T ∈\mathcal{L}(X,Y )$ satisies that $$\|Tx_n − Tx\|_{Y} \to 0,~~~~~as~~n\to\infty$$
, as $n → ∞$.
 whenever $(x_n)_{n≥1}$ is a sequence in $X$ converging weakly to $x ∈ X$ then show that $T ∈\mathcal{K}(X,Y )$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ is reflexive, by Banach-Alaoglu theorem the unit ball of X is weakly compact.

Hence for  $(x_n)_n$ a bounded sequence **(which is contains in a weak compact ball)** there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_j})_j$  that converges weakly in $X$ to some $x$.

> By assumption on $T$ we. have 
>   $$\|Tx_{n_j} − Tx\|_{Y} \to 0$$
>   This shows that T is a compact operator that is $T\in\mathcal{K}(X;Y)$

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. What if $T$ is not compact? How do we know that $x_n$ is bounded?

Comment: @AnnaSchmitz I just prove that T is compact . What is your definition of compact operator?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood something and the explanation helped to understand why the $(x_n)_n$ is a bounded  sequence. I do not get why $(x_n)_n$ has weakly convergent subsequence. Is this because the Banach space is  separable?

Comment: @AnnaSchmitz have ever hear of Banach Alaoglu theorem? if yes what  does it say? and how do you define your compact operator?

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that if $X$ is a reflexive normed space, then any bounded sequence in $X$ has a weakly convergent subsequence.

Now let $(\eta_{n})$ be a bounded sequence in $X$, we are to prove that there is a convergent subsequence $(T(\eta_{n_{k}}))$ of $(T(\eta_{n}))$.

Find some weakly convergent subsequence $\eta_{n_{k}}\rightarrow\eta$ as in the first paragraph. So by assumption we have $\|T(\eta_{n_{k}})-T(\eta)\|\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$, so $(T(\eta_{n_{k}}))$ is convergent.